# Search in json type column in psotgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I have a json like this

```
   {
       "dbInfo": {
          "id":"F",
          "lifeTime":"ACTIVE"
       },
       "name": {
          "firstName":"abc",
          "lastName":"xyz"
       },
       "contactDetails": {
          "email": {
             "localPart":"abc",
             "domain":"gmail.com"
          },
          "mobile": [
             {
                "code":"ISD_91",
                "number":"9658321407"
             }
          ]
       },
       "type": {
          "personType":"WORKER"
       }
    }
```

I want to perform search in database where `number = 9658321407`.

It will return the whole json from the Postgresql database - can anybody help me to write my query? I want to get all json elements that have this number and how can I search if I have more than one number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following format to get the result

-- If the value passing is integer

```
select * from "Your_table" where (select json_array_elements(json_extract_path(json_extract_path("Your_CloumnName",'contactDetails'),'mobile'))->> 'number')::bigint = 9658321407
```

-- If the value passing is string

```
select * from "Your_table" where (select json_array_elements(json_extract_path(json_extract_path("Your_CloumnName",'contactDetails'),'mobile'))->> 'number')= '9658321407'
```

Comment: but is is string so why i use bigint